# How can I loop my Transition?

Tags: transition, skaction, sktransition

Okay I am fairly new to programming and am trying to create a simple game. In the background I'm having an object move from one side of the screen to another and then off the screen using SKAction and SKTransition. All I need to do is loop this transition so when the object goes back off the screen it starts again and comes back on. I'm using SpriteKit.
Here is my code.

//Walls

```
Walls = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Walls")

Walls.position = CGPoint(x: 1080 + Walls.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)

Walls.zPosition = 1

Walls.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: -300 + Walls.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2),duration: 6.0))

self.addChild(Walls)
```

Where can I add in the reapeatActionForever code command or something similar? 
Thanks for your help in advance. Sam. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you're looking for how to use repeatActionForever... Please clarify the question so people don't have to guess

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(/*SKAction or SKSequence etc...*/))
```

I'd put this code in didMoveToView if you want it to start immediately after the scene loads. Otherwise, put it in a block or function where you want it to start. To stop it, change it to:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(/*SKAction or SKSequence etc...*/), withKey: "actionKeyName")
```

Then to stop it:

```
removeAction(forKey: "actionKeyName")
```